# onmouseover and onmouseout images not loading

Tags: javascript, html

On my personal website, I was trying to create some basic animation using `onmouseover`/`onmouseout`. The first URL represents a small (50 x 50) grey scale image and the second URL is the same image but in color.

```
<a><img src="link" onmouseover="this.src='url1'" onmouseout="this.src='url2'"></a>
```

The code is functional, but it has some issues. I've noticed that both on desktop and mobile after the image link has been clicked, the image disappears. It makes sense that the browser wouldn't load any new images, but I was wondering if there was a better alternative.

Comment: What does the image represent? It’s generally a much better idea to use CSS for this kind of thing.

Comment: They're social network logo icons and corresponding links. Ideally, I'd prefer it if either image was displayed when clicked. Do you think that using hover in CSS would solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, using `:hover`/`:active` should solve your problem.

Comment: I am not able to found any issue in your code. http://jsfiddle.net/WfbK4/ May be some path issue is there so it is not able to load the image on mouseover/mouseoyt.

For good practice it is better to achieve this thing by using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @minitech mention, you should use CSS... HTML would be something like:

```
<a><div class="my_image"></div></a>
```

And the CSS:

```
div.my_image {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://www.moo.com/blah.jpg');
}

div.my_image:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.moo.com/otherblah.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a combination of CSS and jQuery for this sort of thing. You could save the images as separate files at the root of your site, or in an /img subdirectory, and then add a class to the link based on the event you wish to change the image for.

Here's some quick code to illustrate:

The HTML:

```
<div id="backgroundImg"><a class="img-link" href=""></a></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#backgroundImg a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('img/grey-50x50.png') no-repeat;
    display: block;
}

#backgroundImg a.color {
    background: url('img/color-50x50.png') no-repeat;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.image-link').mouseover().addClass('color').mouseout().removeClass('color');
```

So you define your image container as a div, load the image through CSS as a background image on the link itself, and then change the class name when the user hovers over the .image-link element.

You could go a step further and combine the two images into one 50x100 image sprite for performance. Then the CSS would like something like:

```
#backgroundImg a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('img/grey-color-50x100.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display: block;
}

#backgroundImg a.color {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}
```

Hope that helps.